# Run something once in a javascript recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

How to run something only once In a Javascript recursion.

Let me explain my question with the `factorial` function

I want to run first line only once.

I have different use cases not this one. And I know very well that I can do `factorial(n=1)`

```
function factorial(n) {
    n = n || 1 //This Line
    if ((n == 0) || (n == 1)) {
        return 1
    }
    return factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often helpful to wrap a function used to evaluate something recursively in an outer function to make the API cleaner:

```
function factorial(n) {
  function compute(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1)
      return 1;
    return n * compute(n - 1);
  }
  return compute(n || 1);
}
```

Now the `n || 1` initialization happens once, when the inner `compute()` function is invoked.

Creating a wrapper like that is even more useful for some combinatorics algorithms ("find all combinations ..." etc).